# How to extract image file name at driver level?

Tags: device-driver, minifilter

I want to extract process image name in a minifilter file system driver.
I am doing something like this, but I get a BSOD. Maybe a mistake in buffer allocation?

```
status = ZwQueryInformationProcess( NtCurrentProcess(),
                                    ProcessImageFileName,
                                    buffer,
                                    returnedLength,
                                    &returnedLength );
```

Comment: Which BSOD? PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ZwQueryInformationProcess` is not a recommended way to get process information.

The best method is to use `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine` and `PsSetLoadImageNotifyRoutine` and prepare your own list of processes.